# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function getusername()

Tags: php

That is the error how do I fix it? Thats all of the code and I am confused with PHP. The template I have auto makes the error logs so I saw this and I can't access profile.php. Please help!

```html
<?php
 require_once('./pieces/header.php');
?>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-8" id="center">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">Profile Editor</div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php $user>getUsername(); ?>" title="Account username." disabled />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php $user>getEmail(); ?>" title="Account email." disabled />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php $user>getMembership(); ?>" title="Account membership." disabled />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
      <input type="password" name="oldpassword" class="form-control"  placeholder="Current Password" title="Current account password." value="" maxlength="32" autocomplete="off" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="New Password" value="" title="New account password." maxlength="32" autocomplete="off" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group no-margn">
      <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Save Changes"/>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is that function even defined?

Comment: @zerkms Its supposed to connect to mysql and when they change username password or email it changes when they click submit and sends it to mysql.

Answer (score 3):

Your sintaxe is wrong.
Your:

`<?php $user>getUsername(); ?>`

Correct:

`<?php $user->getUsername(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks, but I get this now Call to undefined method user::getUsername()

Comment: Well, you need to share your php file... is possible that you are trying to access a class function (static function) using object sintaxe.

`$user::getUsername()` access to static function
`$user->getUsername()` to non static

Comment: The same error? Can you share the code of your class that contain `$user` declaration and its methods?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9, `getUsername` is depreciated. Reference [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountInterface.php/function/AccountInterface%3A%3AgetUsername/8.2.x).

It is recommended to use `getAccountName` or `getDisplayName` instead.

Answer (score -1):

The error 'undefined function' is self explanatory, it means the function you are trying to call does not exist. Your post has the function "getusername()" while your code snippet has the function "getUsername()". Please not the uppercase "U" in the snippet and remember that php is a case sensitive language.

Thanks

Comment: I got a new error like I said earlier Call to undefined method user::getUsername()

Comment: Can you post where the method is defined?

Comment: If what you have up there is all the code, then it won't work. The snippet $user->getUsername() means you have an object named $user which would be an instance of the class User. in the class User, you should have a method called getUsername().  So to recap, you need to first create a class that contains methods(all the getXXX). then you need to create an instance object of that class.